# Pandas - df.fillna(df.mean()) not working on multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
df.head(20)
df = df.fillna(df.mean()).head(20)
```

Below is the result:

[image]

There are many `NaN`.

I want to replace `NaN` by average number, I used `df.fillna(df.mean())`, but useless.

What's the problem??

Comment: request community to close this question as this has been already addressed.

Comment: @JoeFerndz "Closing" of a question does not mean it has a solution. A question only gets closed if there are problems with it and it shouldn't be answered in its current state.

Comment: @ModusTollens, the response from boure Li in Mar 22, 2018 says it works. Unfortunately, this has not been closed since. All good if we want to keep it open.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Maybe you are talking about accepting an answer? Questions don't get "closed" by being answered on Stack Overflow, closing a question means something very specific on this site: that a question is off-topic or not answerable in its current state. So I am not sure what you're commenting on.

Comment: @JoeFerndz https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 1):

I have got it !!  before replace the NaN number, I need to reset index at first.
Below is code:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

now everything is okay!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
for i in df.columns:
  df.fillna(df[i].mean(),inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each column in your DataFrame has at least one non-numeric value (in the rows #0 and partially #1). When you apply `.mean()` to a DataFrame, it skips all non-numeric columns (in your case, all columns). Thus, the `NaN`s are not replaced. Solution: drop the non-numeric rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be your columns are not float or int type. check with df.dtypes. if return object then mean wont work. change the type using df.astype()

Comment: looks like a comment